# Example involving direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am trying to come up with a counter example to the following:

Let $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$, then if there exists a subspace $T$ of $V$ such that $U_{1} \oplus T= U_{2} \oplus T$

then $U_{1}=U_{2}$

I am wondering if my following example makes sense in illustarating why this isnt true.

Consider $$V=M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$$

And $U_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $,
$U_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c \\ 0 & d \\ \end{pmatrix} $ and

$T=\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ w & z\\ \end{pmatrix} $

$V=U_{1} \oplus T= U_{2} \oplus T$
To me it seems to work, but I am just a bit confused sometimes because would it really make no difference having an entry be x, and another a+x, ( it seems like these are the same because we could take a=0)

Anyways, does this make sense?

Comment: How does $W=U_1$ in this instance? $U_1$ is a subspace of $W$.

Comment: @ElChapo typo, fixed thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because these are not direct sums. Remember that in a direct sum we must have that the only way the sum of two elements is zero is if  both are zero. In this instance I can see two different ways for the sum of two elements to equal zero. Do you?

Comment: Would it be say if x was -a, w was -b for example?

Comment: That is exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

The notation in the statement of the question is kind of poor.  As I would interpret it, the equation $$U_1\oplus T=U_2\oplus T$$ is actually three statements at once:

1. $U_1\cap T=0$, so $U_1+T$ is the internal direct sum of $U_1$ and $T$.
2. $U_2\cap T=0$, so $U_2+T$ is the internal direct sum of $U_2$ and $T$.
3. $U_1+T=U_2+T$.

With this interpretation, your example doesn't work, because it does not satisfy (1) and (2).  (Indeed, if you don't require (1) and (2), you can just let $T=V$ and let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be *any* two distinct subspaces of $V$.)

An example that does work can be obtained as follows:

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, let $U_1$ be the span of $(1,0)$, let $U_2$ be the span of $(1,1)$, and let $T$ be the span of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why in your example would we let T be (0,1) instead of U2 being (0,1), is it because we dont want one coordinate to be double the other?

Comment: It would also work if you swapped $T$ and $U_2$ (i.e., $T$ is spanned by $(1,1)$ and $U_2$ is spanned by $(0,1)$).  There are many possibilities besides the example I gave.